# Cookie lost between pages

Tags: php, cookies

I ran into a problem where a cookie is set in one method of a class and in another method the same cookie is not defined. To make it more clear, here is the code of the first method:

```
public function checklogpass($name,$psw) 
{

    try {
        $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=informal','vad','6989');

        $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

        $pdo->exec('SET NAMES "utf8"');
    }
    catch(PDOException $e) {

        echo $e->getMessage();
    }

    $sql = 'SELECT login,password FROM users WHERE login = :name AND password = :psw';

    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);

    $stmt->bindValue(':name',$name);
    $stmt->bindValue(':psw',$psw);
    $stmt->execute();

    $row = $stmt->fetch();

    if (isset($name) && isset($psw)) {

        if($name == $row['login'] && $psw == $row['password']) {

            setcookie("log",$name,time()+3600);
            header('Location: /OpenS/app/auth/checkin.php');

        } else {

            $_SESSION['errors'] = 'Failed login or password';
            header('Location: /OpenS/app/views/form.php');
        }
    }

}
```

And this another method of another class:

```
public function getUser()
{
    if (isset($_COOKIE["log"])){

        return $_COOKIE["log"];

        header('Location: /OpenS/app/views/home.php');

    } else {

         $_SESSION['notify'] = 'You are not logged in';

         header('Location: /OpenS/app/views/home.php');
    }
}
```

When I enter an incorrect username or password, the script tells me correctly "Failed login or password". However, when I enter the correct username and password, the cookie is set, the redirect to the homepage takes place, but on the homepage it will say "You are not logged in".

I solved this problem by putting the information in the session, but I don't think this is the right solution. How can I do this better?

Comment: Some inteligent/consistant code indentation would make your code easier to read and therefore easier to debug

Answer (score 0):

Your current approach is fundamentally wrong. By setting a cookie "log" with a value equal to the username you open yourself up to anyone logging as anyone they please... without requiring any login credentials...

A cookie is a piece of data that is stored on the client's computer. All data that is on the client's computer can be altered as they please. They can, among other things, just change the value of the cookie, and log in as the administrator for example.

So, how do you solve this problem? You put the information in the session, like you already did. The session cookie is reasonably safe, as it is hard to find a cookie value that collides with a session of someone else. Session variables are never sent to the user, and instead stored on the server. Only the session cookie is sent back and forth between the browser and the client.